# Find All User's AppData Directories

Tags: c#, .net

My project is a plugin to a much larger project. A bug in the larger project creates a file that will cause my application to crash. They are already aware of the issue and are addressing it, but in the meantime the only work around is to delete a certain file in the appdata directory for each user.

The plan is that during installation of the smaller plugin, to navigate to every user's appdata directory to delete a problematic file (if it exists). Is there any way to find each User's appdata directory. Remember this is an install, so we will have admin privileges. Some of the things I have seen is to use

```
WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(IntPtr someUser)
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

Then it would just be a matter of somehow getting the IntPtr, which I am unsure how to get.

That is the best solution I have right now. So how do I get the IntPtr of each user? Or is there a better solution?

The next best that I can think of would simply be to go through all directories of `C:\Users\eachUser\AppData\` and deleting the file as it exists. But then again, in XP that location would have to be `C:\Documents and Settings\eachUser\Application Data\` and I would be creating operating system specific code. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [WindowsIdentity.Impersonate Method (IntPtr userToken)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx):

IntPtr userToken is...

> The handle of a Windows account token. This token is usually retrieved through a call to unmanaged code, such as a call to the Win32 API [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function.

So, you can't do it this way unless you have all the usernames and passwords.

Edit:  Why not delete the file at runtime for just the current user?  Does your plugin have permission to do this?

Edit 2: You can use the installing user's directory from `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`, and then use [Directory.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c1sez4sc.aspx) to find the other users that have a profile.  Then, you can tack on the special folder name.  Pretty round-about, but it might work in your "pinch".

Comment: Our plugin gets run from the larger application, and the larger application crashes before even running our code. It crashes because it doesn't expect our plugin to be there and the file we are deleting is the file that lists the plugins, forcing it to recreate the plugin list.

Comment: Then, I suppose my Edit2 is your best option.

Comment: I was afraid I would have to do an ugly round about way of doing this. Thanks for your help, though.